# problems with bluetooth with my ASUS S551LB

Tags: 14.04, wireless, bluetooth, asus

I have a problem with my laptop asus S551LB with Ubuntu 14.04

when I initialize Ubuntu, appears a message like this:

Bluetooth: error in firmware loading err = -110,len = 448, size = 4096
[..] Bluetooth: loading patch file failed

So the problem is that when I try to enable bluetooth, it doesn't work

So I don't know what I have to do

I have put the comands lspci | grep --ignore-case blue and lsusb | grep --ignore-case blue but it doesn't appear nothing

Would you help me?

Thank you!

P.D. I have tried with the command rfkill list and rfkill unlock bluetooth and it doesn't solve the problem

Comment: Please [edit] your question and provide the output to `lspci | grep --ignore-case blue` and `lsusb | grep --ignore-case blue`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like that model has an Atheros Wifi/BT combo card and the AR3012 has issues in Linux with the xhci drivers and the ath3k module needs to be loaded later.  The only workaround I have found involves blacklisting ath3k and using rc.local to load the module
`echo "blacklist ath3k" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/ath3k.conf`
 and

```
gksudo gedit /etc/rc.local
```

and add

```
modprobe ath3k
```

above exit 0
Save, exit program and reboot

If you check /lib/firmware/ar3k and there is no such folder you will need to install package linux-firmware also

Comment: I have enable my NVIDIA Graphics Card and now it detects he bluetooth. Sometimes the bluetooth is soft blocked but I solve these problem with the rfkill command.

Comment: What is the result of `lsusb`

Comment: Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0bda:0139 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5139 Card Reader Controller
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 04f2:b3d8 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 1bcf:0005 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

Comment: Ok I do what you have said and it works

Comment: Can you accept my answer so it will hopefully help others, even if it is more of a workaround